# Disabling Export to MS Excel option on right click in browser using Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, internet-explorer

Is there any javascript to disable "export to microsoft excel option" on right click in browser. though it can be done using web.config, but there is this need to do it using js.
TIA
Bibhu

Answer (score 0):

I would be a security risk to allow that kind of control on the client. Those menus are from add-ons, so they would be giving power over personalization and possibly security add-ons. So as far as I can tell, it can not be done from the server side.